# Need to suppress rowcount headers when using \G

Tags: mysql

Is there a command to suppress the rowcount headers and asterisks when using '\G' to execute a SQL statement?  I am executing mysql with the `-s` and `--skip-column-name` options, but these don't suppress the rowcounts.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions

## SUGGESTION #1 : Use [**grep command**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_grep.htm)

You could use the [**grep command**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_grep.htm) to filter it out

```
mysql -u... -p... -ANe"SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" | grep -v "^\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*"
```

Here is a quick demonstration:

```
[root@***** ~]# mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G"
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.64.76.250
                  Master_User: replicant
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004474
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 76212800
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.013419
                Relay_Log_Pos: 76212945
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004474
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 76212800
              Relay_Log_Space: 76213137
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2013
                Last_IO_Error: error reconnecting to master 'replicant@10.64.76.250:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
[root@***** ~]# mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" | grep -v "^\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*"
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.64.76.250
                  Master_User: replicant
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004474
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 111533085
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.013419
                Relay_Log_Pos: 111533230
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004474
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 111533085
              Relay_Log_Space: 111533422
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2013
                Last_IO_Error: error reconnecting to master 'replicant@10.64.76.250:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
[root@***** ~]#
```

## SUGGESTION #2 : Use [**tail command**](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tail.htm) (if expecting one row of output)

Run the `\G` command to a text file. Use tail to print everything but the first line:

```
[root@***** ~]# mysql -uroot -p -ANe"SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G" > junk.txt
[root@***** ~]# LINECOUNT=`wc -l < junk.txt`
[root@***** ~]# (( LINECOUNT-- ))
[root@***** ~]# tail -${LINECOUNT} junk.txt
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.64.76.250
                  Master_User: replicant
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004474
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 411163018
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.013419
                Relay_Log_Pos: 411163163
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004474
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 411163018
              Relay_Log_Space: 411163355
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2013
                Last_IO_Error: error reconnecting to master 'replicant@10.64.76.250:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
[root@***** ~]#
```

Give it a Try !!!